# Error while installing sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

When I try to run (on Windows 10):

```
pip install sklearn
```

I get a long list of

```
copying sklearn\tests\test_pipeline.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\sklearn\tests
    copying sklearn\tests\test_random_projection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\sklearn\tests
    copying sklearn\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\sklearn\tests
    running build_clib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler using build_clib
    building 'libsvm-skl' library
    compiling C sources
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\sklearn
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\sklearn\svm
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\sklearn\svm\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\sklearn\svm\src\libsvm
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I"c:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" /EHsc /Tpsklearn\svm\src\libsvm\libsvm_template.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\sklearn\svm\src\libsvm\libsvm_template.obj
    Could not locate executable cl.exe
    Executable cl.exe does not exist

    error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I"c:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" /EHsc /Tpsklearn\svm\src\libsvm\libsvm_template.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\sklearn\svm\src\libsvm\libsvm_template.obj" failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files\python\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\$andu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-cho6u5yy\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\$andu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-977em_sb-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\$andu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-cho6u5yy\scikit-learn\
```

None of the suggestions found online worked for me.

How do I deal with this?

---

I have `numpy-1.12.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` and `scipy-0.19.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have cl.exe in your PATH.

cl.exe should be under your (visual studio folder)\VC\bin

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to the Windows Explorer location where you placed the wheel file
2. Click in the address bar and type `cmd`
3. Type `pip install <filename>.whl` and press enter

Comment: Following your suggestion, I download scikit_learn-0.18.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_i686.whl and scikit_learn-0.18.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn/0.18.1#downloads. I try to install them both but I still get an error:

scikit_learn-0.18.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: I looked at the py version when I have downloaded them.. win files (cp35) give the same error. Should I understand that the win files cp36 are not available yet?

Comment: You said you are using Windows 10, right? That wheel file is for Linux. Look at the file name to pick the correct wheel file. You will probably need one for win_amd64 if you have a 64 bit processor. Also make sure the file aligns to your Python version.

Comment: Alright then, try typing `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade pip. Then try installing again.

Comment: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\program files\python\lib\site-packages`. I get the same error.

Comment: Replace win_amd64 with win32 in the file name and try again. Pip may be detecting your operating system as 32 bit.

Comment: The error persists: `scikit_learn-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`.